# Filter section missing in control panel -> Programs and Features in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am unable to filter the program listing in Controls Panel's "Programs and Features".
I am missing the filter textbox like the one in the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems you are using the classic theme. Do you have that field with the normal theme?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in your classic view you have turned off the search box.

### How to Confirm whether Search box is TURNED OFF?

1. Click **`Windows Key+F`** to open a search window
2. If you are getting an error message then it is turned off

Once it is confirmed then follow below steps:-

### How to TURN ON on search box?

1. Open **`Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features`**
2. Click **`Turn Windows Features on or off`** link from left side navigation
3. You will see **`Windows Features`** window is opened
4. Scroll down till end (Just like this, see the screenshot)
   [image]
5. Look at **`Windows Search`** check box

   - If check box is **UNCHECKED** then search functionality is turned off

     - Check the `Windows Search` box
     - Click on **OK**
     - Click **Restart Now** button
     - After restart, you will see search box
   - If check box is **CHECKED** then seach funtionality is already turned on

     - Do nothing and just close the window
     - There should be something else wrong on your PC